# How do I remove the space below my header img

Tags: css

Can someone please tell me no matter what I do there is a small gap below my header img.
Here is my css

```
.site-header {
position: relative;
border-bottom: 5px solid #121212;
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 0px !important;


}
```

My site
[Gfx hideout](http://gfxhideout.com)

Ps on a tablet so i dont have access to inspect.
thank you for your time.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Better still provide a [MCVE] . Reducing a problem to its smallest amount of code to replicate it is an essential skill in debugging. Live sites are difficult for us to work with, specially if you are actively trying to fix it your self. Further more the question becomes useless for future users once you actually solve the problem. Finally, avoid using `!important` : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:block` css to the header image

This will remove the space below the `img` tag, which is `display:inline` by default.

The space you are seeing is for descenders. This space is kept for characters like "y" ,"p".

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`display:block;` to the header img

> `header img{display:block;}`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gautam Naik that you could set your image CSS to be `display:block`, but another problem is that you have:

```
border-bottom: 5px solid #121212;
```

inside of your .site-header class, which to me does not make a lot of sense and also adds excess space between your header image, navigation, and content div.  Try removing it to test what I am talking about out!